# Deleting rows in excel without affecting the Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet where Iam trying to add the serial numbers in each row using the below formula

=IF(C149<>"";MAX($B$149:OFFSET(B150;-1;0))+0.1;"")

However, whenever I delete the rows in B column there will be error value in all other rows like #N/A

Whether it is possible to delete the rows without affecting the Formula ?

I heard there is a excel function "INDEX" to be used, please reply with your answers how to apply INDEX function to the above Formula

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, Iam using Excel 2010 version

Comment: Hi pnuts can you please help me in this formula query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be related to `$B$149` When you delete a row the $ means that the 149 cannot change accordingly like the `C149` and `B150` would , this may then mean that it is pointing to incorrect data after the deletion.

Comment: Hi your concept is not working, is it possible for you help me out using Indirect function of excel in formula /

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the answer you were asking for, but google picks this out for deleting without breaking formaulas - so anyone landing here from google...

The formulas break because you are removing cells from the spreadsheet - chainging the structure of the sheet. Where as what you want to do is just remove the data, and have all the remaining data move up.

One way is to select all the data below the line you want cleared (plus one blank line at the end) - then copy that range (to the clipboard) and paste it all back in one row higher.

Not a great solution - but it works - I found this question looking for a better way! :)